# make image's particular part click listener in android

Tags: android

I have an android application, which needs to display an image and make that images particular part click listenable... anybody please help me with some hints..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to work with an [onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html). The [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) object which will be passed to the handler method [onTouch()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) contains the coordinates of the touch event that was made. So with this data you should be able to calculate which part of your image was clicked.